# Shouldn't there be an option on Android OS to undo the misplaced or deleted text entered on apps provided by the keyboard?

Tags: android, user-experience, undo-redo

**Few cases of my problem:**

Multiple times I have encountered the problem of deleting the text in android and was unable to undo or get that text back.

1. Selecting the whole paragraph of text to format and then by mistake replacing the selected text with the single letter and then unable to get back that typed email text.
2. After typing a long email you mistakenly replaced the text with a text and then unable to get back that typed email text.

So I would like to know that is that possible to undo the misplaced text on Android.
I have also found that on other OSes such as in iPhone(although I have never used it) it is possible to undo and get back the text using gesture of shaking the device. Also, we all know that in Windows OS we have the undo shortcut (Ctrl+Z). This feature was also present in Windows Phone.

Also, I have found that this feature is implemented by very few apps on Android that helped me to get back the misplaced text.

Shouldn't there be an option on Android OS to undo the misplaced or deleted text entered on apps provided by the keyboard itself?

Answer (score 2):

The back button serves as Undo or Cancel (or Back) in many apps, but won't help with a typo in a text box, it's more likely to lose everything you've typed in there than undo the last bit of typing.

This app can help with this https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.catchingnow.undo  ...